# time series alignment with continuous and categorical data

Tags: algorithm

I have pairs of series of timed measurements I want to align.  I have
annotators judging and marking ambiguous events in a signal and want
to optimally match their times and events.  The input is four columns:
the event onset times and labels for one annotator, and the times and
labels for the other annotator.  For example (as rows):

```
annotator_1_times: .34, .39, .50, .68, .88

annotator_1_label:   A,   X,   Q,   L,   Z

annotator_2_times: .33, .41, .67, .90

annotator_2_label:   A,   X,   L,   X
```

Annotators don't necessarily have the same number of events when they
interpret the same signal.  Annotators in general are expected to have
similar but nonidentical labels, and similar but nonidentical times.

How this should be done depends on some sort of cost function --
something that will decide how "bad" it is for a time to be off a
certain amount, and for two labels to disagree.

A desirable output in my example case:

```
   annotator_1_times: .34, .39, .50, .68, .88

   annotator_1_label:   A,   X,   Q,   L,   Z

   annotator_2_times: .33, .41,  [], .67, .90    <-note gap inserted

   annotator_2_label:   A,   X,  [],   L,   X
```

Stuff I would then do post hoc:

```
time_mismatch_dif: .01, .02,  XX, .01, .02    <- for computing agreemt

label_mismatches_:   0,   0, ADD,   0, SUBST  <- for computing agreemt
```

The hard part is to know where to insert the gaps.

If need be, I can do just the numerical alignments and separately just
the label alignments and then merge them somehow.  I know there are
character alignment algorithms (e.g. in genetics) and there must be
time-series alignment algorithms.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) problem, and you can adapt the same algorithm there.

Firstly define your cost function.

Then, run a dynamic programming on a quadratic table: for each `i` and `j` calculate `ans[i][j]`, that is the 'cost of alignment' of first `i` events from the first annotator and first `j` events from the second. This can be done in three ways:

- either you align `i` and `j`, then `ans[i][j]` becomes `ans[i-1][j-1] + costAlignment(a[i],b[j])`
- either you align `i` and 'gap', then `ans[i][j]` becomes `ans[i-1][j] + costGap(a[i])`
- either you align `j` and 'gap', then `ans[i][j]` becomes `ans[i][j-1] + costGap(b[j])`

You should choose minimum of three options.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to understand how quadratic tables work but I'm not quite there. I think I get how to make these decisions locally at each choice point, but not how this will work for a global minimum over the whole pair of (double) vectors without creating a 3-way branching tree at each new item in the list (3-way because of 3 options of {match,add-gap-i,add-gap-j} ). I think Needleman-Wunsch would come close if it were only character vectors, but I have both characters and time-alignments for each character.

Comment: @DSwingley, you might need to read about dynamic programming in general. In short, you will in fact have a 3-way branching tree, but it will have many identical subtrees occurring again and again. For example, from (i,j) position you branch to (i-1,j) and to (i,j-1), not to mention a third branch. But from (i-1,j) you branch, among others, to (i-1,j-1), and from (i,j-1) you branch to (i-1,j-1). These two (i-1,j-1) branches are absolutely identical, hence you do not need to recalculate values there once again.

Comment: @DSwingley, you can indeed think of it as of a tree, and even implement recursive algorithm. It will be very slow, but it will work. And then just consider that you recursive algorithm really solves each subproblem many times. Add memorization of the already calculated results and you will instantly achieve the fast DP solution.